# how can i get the pixel shader asm code "Ld"?I'm writing HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl, sample, texture2d, pixel-shader

When I'm reading the asm code ,I dont know how to get the instruction "ld" just below.
Which function should I use in HLSL to get it?
Or had it be replaced with the update of versions?
The following is asm code:

```
ld r0.xyzw r0.xyzw t19.xyzw
```

I tried to use texture2D in HLSL  but when compiled it was "sample " not "ld".

Answer (score 1):

`ld` is a Shader Model 4.0 or later instruction. Which shader profile & HLSL compiler are you using?

The [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-to-load) member of a texture object is typically how you do this in modern HLSL.

```
Texture2D<float4> g_Input : register( t0 ); 


float4 pixel = g_Input.Load(...);
```

Comment: I tried and got "ld"！Your support is greatly appreciated！plus:Im decompiling shader asm to hlsl in C,Is there any existing tools that can help?

Comment: excuse me ,I got another question here ,how can I get the function round_z?